# lpr cannot open connection to localhost

Tags: linux, printing, lpr

I would like to know how to print with lp commands without using CUPS.

If I send a file to print with this command:

```
cat fichero.txt | lpr
```

I've got this error:

```
lpr cannot open connection to localhost
```

How can I print or config my system to print using lp commands?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, there are several packages providing `/usr/bin/lpr`, one of which is cups-bsd. If you install an alternative you should be able to print without cups. On Redhat-based distros the command you can use to find packages providing a binary is `yum whatprovides`.

```
➜  ~ apt-file search /usr/bin/lpr
cups-bsd: /usr/bin/lpr
cups-bsd: /usr/bin/lprm
dvi2ps: /usr/bin/lprdvi
lpr: /usr/bin/lpr
lpr: /usr/bin/lprm
lprng: /usr/bin/lpr
lprng: /usr/bin/lprm
```

Comment: I have installed cups-bsd and If I try to print with cat file.txt | lpr I've got this error: lpr: Error - the task scheduler program does not respond.

Comment: But you said you didn't want CUPS - maybe try "lpr" or "lprng"?

Comment: lpr and lprng doesn't work to me :(